# JUCE Message Thread (1): EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0) when trying to build plugin

Tags: xcode, audio, plugins, juce

I'm trying to create a VST plug-in using JUCE framework by video tutorial but I've been having this error: JUCE Message Thread (1): EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0). I have no clue why it happens, here is the code that causes it.

```
juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout SimpleEQAudioProcessor::createParameterLayout(){
    juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout layout;
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("LowCut Freq", "LowCut Freq", juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f), 20.f));
    
   layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("HighCut Freq", "HighCut Freq", juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f), 20000.f));
    
   layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("Peak Freq", "Peak Freq", juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f), 750.f));
    
   layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("Peak Gain", "Peak Gain", juce::NormalisableRange<float>(-24.f, 24.f, 0.5f, 1.f), 0.f));
    
   layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("Peak Quality", "Peak Quality", juce::NormalisableRange<float>(0.1f, 10.f, 0.05f, 1.f), 1.f));
    
    juce::StringArray stringArray;
    for( int i = 0; i<4; ++i){
        juce::String str;
        str << (12 + i*12);
        str << " db/Oct";
        stringArray.add(str);
    }
    
   layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterChoice>("LowCut Slope", "LowCut Slope", stringArray, 0));
    
   layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterChoice>("HighCut Slope", "HighCut Slope", stringArray, 0));
    
    return layout;
}
```

The layout manipulations seem to cause the error. The console also displays pointer to current AudioProcessorEditor.

Comment: Have the same problem from the same tutorial...

Comment: It actually happens on every project

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because version hint is 0. We can fix it by setting version number when adding parameter:

```cpp
layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>(ParameterID { "LowCutFreq",  1 }, // here
                                                           "LowCut Freq",
                                                           juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 0.25f),
                                                           20.f));
```

Reference:
https://forum.juce.com/t/how-to-set-a-parameter-version-hint/52011